# Back-end login only one session

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I've installed (on local in my computer with LARAGON webserver) TYPO3 v7.6.32 ..all right, (except opnssl php extension alert message).

But the real issue is the Backend login, I can login only once time, if I logged out and login immediately after all is fine, is ok! ..., but if I restart the computer, start the server apache/php ecc.. the message appears "Oops, an error occurred" and I can not login ... I have to reinstall TYPO3.

Screenshot here https://ibb.co/87r0CDy

in "LocalConfiguration.php" I've change 'loginSecurityLevel' => 'normal',

What can I do to avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you checked all logs? Log in TYPO3 backend? PHP error log? There should be more detailed information.

Comment: No, I can't login after the "Oops..an error occurred" error screen. I have to do a new installation of Typo3 :(

Comment: Then have a look at table "sys_log". And PHP error log?

Comment: ok, Php error log not exist in my Laragon.. and sys_log look the screenshot: 

PHP log is: https://ibb.co/ccRMRt8 

sys log is: https://ibb.co/RDfRY6Q

THanks

Comment: Nothin useful to see on screenshot. What Uncaught TYPO3 Exception happens? And please copy text.

Comment: Enable TYPO3 error using `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0` You will get better idea.

Comment: Thanks! 
Now I managed to fix, I activated (installed) RSA authentication for TYPO3 from the Backend, and it seems that now there are no issues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the extension rsaauth. If you change in LocalConfiguration.php  'loginSecurityLevel' to 'normal', after first login with installed rsaauth, t3 changed 'loginSecurityLevel' in 'LocalConfiguration' back to 'rsa'. The only way to stop this, is to deactivate the extension 'rsaauth'. Do this only in local testing and developing installations. Deactivating rsaauth makes a T3 installation unsecure.